# Is Java 8 New Date API available in Android N?

Tags: android, api, datetime, java-8, android-7.0-nougat

Will Android N support Java 8 Date/Time API?

As this Android blog said: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2016/03/first-preview-of-android-n-developer.html

> Improved Java 8 language support - We’re excited to bring Java 8
>   language features to Android. With Android's Jack compiler, you can
>   now use many popular Java 8 language features, including lambdas and
>   more, on Android versions as far back as Gingerbread. The new features
>   help reduce boilerplate code. For example, lambdas can replace
>   anonymous inner classes when providing event listeners. Some Java 8
>   language features --like default and static methods, streams, and
>   functional interfaces -- are also now available on N and above. With
>   Jack, we’re looking forward to tracking the Java language more closely
>   while maintaining backward compatibility.

It says:

> With Android's Jack compiler, you can
>   now use many popular Java 8 language features, including lambdas and
>   more

Yes, lambda expression supported. What about Java 8 New Date/Time API?

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: take a look at https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the documentation, the default and static interface methods are supported. Please find the supported Java 8 features here in this link.

http://developer.android.com/preview/j8-jack.html#supported-features